# How to add timestamp to ffmpeg in nginx-rtmp-module

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg

I use nginx-rtmp-module and ffmpeg to record rtmp video stream to mp4 file, but I want to know how to add timestamp to the mp4 file.

My config as below:

```
rtmp
{
    server
    {
        listen 1935;
        timeout 10s;
        application mylive   {
            live on;
            exec /usr/bin/ffmpeg -i rtmp://localhost/$app/$name -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f mp4 /home/ubuntu/video/${name}.mp4;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to record the file with the name as ${name}-`date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S`, but how can i do?

Answer (score 0):

Solved

```
application mylive {
    live on;
    recorder all {
        record all;
        record_max_size 100000K;
        record_path /var/video/mylive;
        record_suffix -%Y%m%d_%H%M%S.mp4;
    }
}
```